# Confirmation for new registered users seems to be not working on my development

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.4

I'm overwriting `registerAction()` with my own logic as follow:

```
public function saveAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

    $user = $userManager->createUser();

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    $entity = new SysUsuario();
    $form = $this->createForm(new UsuarioType(), $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $user_data = $request->get('user_register');
    $profile_data = $request->get('user_register')['perfil'];

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

        $user->setUsername($profile_data['rif']);
        $user->setEmail($user_data['email']);
        $user->setPlainPassword($user_data['password']);
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $role = $profile_data['roleType'];
        if ($role === "O") {
            $user->addRole("ROLE_OPERADOR");
        }
        elseif ($role === "CH") {
            $user->addRole("ROLE_CENTRO_HIPICO");
        }

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        $profile = new SysPerfil();
        $profile->setPersJuridica($profile_data['persJuridica']);
        $profile->setRif($profile_data['rif']);
        $profile->setCi($profile_data['ci']);
        $profile->setNombre($profile_data['nombre']);
        $profile->setApellido($profile_data['apellido']);
        $profile->setRoleType($profile_data['roleType']);
        $profile->setUser($user);

        $em->persist($profile);
        $em->flush();

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }
    else {
        $errors = $this->getFormErrors($formProfile);
    }

    return new JsonResponse(array('status' => true, 'errors' => $errors));
}
```

All it's working fine, users are registered and profile are created, email with token arrive to my inbox but when I click on the link I got redirected to login page without any confirmation around activation successfully or failed or whatever. I don't know if I'm right but after the register is done I look into `user` table and `confirmation_token` is always empty, is  that right? Also it's right to enabled the user by doing `$user->setEnabled(true)` after update the user trough `UserManager`? What is missing here? Why `confirmation_token` is not set? What I'm trying to do is prevent users to login if they are not confirmed they account trough the email that FOSUser send, any advice or help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found where my error was, I forgot to set `confirmation: true` under FOSUser configurations at `config.yml` file:

```
# FOSUserBundle
fos_user:
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true # I've missed this one
```